# A question about the Fitting subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm stuck somewhere in the following problem, I would appreciate if you could help:

**Problem:** Let $H$ be a subgroup of a finite group $G$. Then,
$H \leq F(G)$ iff $\langle H, H^x \rangle$ is nilpotent for all $x \in G,$ where $F(G)$ is the fitting subgroup of $G.$

**My attempt:** One direction is easily follows. If $H \leq F(G),$ then $H^x \leq F(G)$ for all $x \in G$ since $F(G)$ is normal in $G.$ This give us that $\langle H, H^x \rangle \leq F(G).$ Since $F(G)$ is nilpotent, being a subgroup  $\langle H, H^x \rangle$ must be nilpotent. We are done. For the other direction, if we show that that $H$ is nilpotent and normal then the result follows because $F(G)$ is the largest normal nilpotent subgroup in $G.$ Nilpotency of $H$ immediately follows since $\langle H, H^x \rangle$ is nilpotent for all $x \in G$ (take $x=1_G$).  To see why $H$ is normal in $G$, assume the contrary. Then there exist $a \in G\setminus N_G(H).$ Using the hypothesis that $\langle H, H^a\rangle$ is nilpotent, we get that $H$ is a proper subgroup of its normalizer in the $\langle H, H^a\rangle.$ How can I get the desired result from this point?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

See M.I. Isaacs, [Finite Group Theory](https://books.google.nl/books?id=pCLhYaMUg8IC&pg=PA45&hl=nl&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false), Theorem (2.12) (R. Baer). The proof is based on induction on $|G|$, uses the Zipper Lemma and the fact that $H \subseteq F(G)$ iff $H$ is nilpotent and subnormal in $G$.